# Как получить дочерний(-ие) элемент(-ы) определенного блока?

Tags: javascript

```js
let image=document.querySelector(".parent").children; //понятно что children возвращает NodeList[img, img, img, img]. 
image.addEventListener("click", function(){

alert("You clicked on image"); //Что-то неправильно, поэтому не выводится содержимое alert
});
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<img src="img-1.jpg"alt="image"> 
<img src="img-2.jpg"alt="image">
<img src="img-3.jpg"alt="image">
<img src="img-4.jpg"alt="image">
</div> <!-- /.parent -->
```

P.S. Здесь простая ошибка думаю, просто когда изучаю сложные вещи забываются простые -_-

Comment: Если понятно что `children` это `NodeList`, почему добавляешь ему слушатель события? :) Добавить листенер можно только отдельному ноду (типа элемент), но не коллекции элементов. `for (const el of images) el.addEventListener('click', handlerFunc);` - и общую handlerFunc объяви отдельно.

Comment: А вообще, разумнее делегировать обработку событий товарищу `.parent`, раз он содержит все элементы одинаково реагирующие на событие.

Comment: @yar85 , Потому добавила чтоб допустить глупую ошибку )) Зная что с помощью цикла for надо решить эту проблему, взяла задала вопрос здесь ) (Видимо мозг устал от меня, не хочеть думать, хочет увидеть готовый код ) )

Answer (score 0):

```js
//With using for() {}
let images = document.querySelectorAll(".parent img");
let func=function(){
alert("You clicked on image");
}
for(let i=0; i<images.length; i++){
 images[i].addEventListener("click", func);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// With using for of

let images = document.querySelectorAll(".parent img");
let func=function(){
alert("You clicked on image");
    }
for (let image of images)
image.addEventListener("click", func);
```